# Returns null getrequest retrofit kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, get-request

I have this function in my `viewmodel` and I want to retrieve a list of locations with a get Request.
But when I call the function `fetchAllLocations` from the fragment this function returns null. But in the `onResponse` method the list locations isn't null. I don't know why locations is null outside of the `onResponse` method.

```
      fun fetchAllLocations(): List<Location>?
            {
        
                val call = apiInterface?.fetchAllLocation()
                var locations: List<Location>?  = null
        
                call?.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Location>> {
        
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Location>>, response: Response<List<Location>>) {
                        locations = response.body()
        
        
        
                    }
        
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Location>>, t: Throwable) {
                        
                    }
                })
                return locations
            }
        }
```

Comment: because it is asynchronous process

Comment: This is due to async behavior.  call?.enqueue is an async operation. So when this API call , it returns a list of the location under response callback. Since you are returning location, so fetchAllLocations will return null locations always.

Comment: How should i retrieve the data then?

Comment: Instead of returning, You can use live data in ViewModel and observe this livedata from the fragment. Inside onResponse callback ,post value in livedata

Comment: Do you have a example how i could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this live data in your viewmodel

```
   val locationLiveData by lazy { MutableLiveData<<List<Location>>() }
        
    fun fetchAllLocations(){
            
                    val call = apiInterface?.fetchAllLocation()
                    call?.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Location>> {
            
                        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Location>>, response: Response<List<Location>>) {
                            locations = response.body()
                            locationLiveData.postValue(locations)
                        }
            
                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Location>>, t: Throwable) {}
                    })
                }
   }
```

Observe this live-data from your fragment class.

```
viewModel.locationLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            //here you will get list
        })
```

Ref Project : https://github.com/droiddevgeeks/MovieSearch ( Java)
https://github.com/droiddevgeeks/TrendingRepo ( Kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit run async processes , so you actually returning the initial value of your list which is null , so you need to need use LiveData , which is a part of Android Jetpack and it use class Observer class to observe for change in the data , you can register an observer in your case and observe for its value to change , when this happen you can actually use that data .
For more information , you can check the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)